# Trace the particular row from a result set and then getting column value of that row

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, jsp

```
<%
while(rs.next())
        {
                String flight_no=rs.getString("flight_no");
           String flight_name=rs.getString("flight_name");     
                   String from =rs.getString("from");     
           String to=rs.getString("to"); 

           SimpleDateFormat reFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD") ;
Date activityDate =rs.getDate("departure");
java.sql.Date departure = new java.sql.Date(activityDate.getTime());

           String departure_time=rs.getString("departure_time");     
           String arrival_time=rs.getString("arrival_time");     
    int avail_seatss=rs.getInt("avail_seats");
    %>
<TR>

<TD align=left><%out.print(to);%></TD>
<TD align=left width=10%><value="<%out.print(flight_no); %>"/></TD>
<TD align=left width=20%><value="<%out.print(from);%>"/></TD>
<TD align=left width=20%><value="<%out.print(to);%>"/></TD>
<TD align=left width=10%><value="<%out.print(departure);%>"/></TD>
<TD align=left width=10%><value="<%out.print(departure_time);%>"/></TD>
<TD align=left width=10%><value="<%out.print(arrival_time);%>"/></TD>
<TD align=left width=5%><value="<% out.print(avail_seatss);%>"/></TD>
<TD align=left width=10%><input type="button" name="Book_Now" value="Book Now">
</TR>
}
```

I have a sql resultset in jsp. i have added a new column which has a button.
i want that when user clicks that button , it fetches the column value of that particular row .i find a method to only trace rows in javascript but i didnt find any method to do so in jsp. i was able to track the row but how to get the value of column of that row wasnt working. Help ! 
In the above example i want that when user clicks the particular row's book now button then it returns me the flight no. of that row. The result set contains multiple rows and result is purely dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate an `onclick` method for the `button` like

```
onclick="book_now(this)"
```

Then in `book_now` function you can get the flight number with

```
function book_now(elem){
  var flight_no = elem.parentNode.parentNode.children[1].innerHTML;
  // do your stuff with flight_no
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u9CPR/1/)**

**EDIT**

You can get that `flight_no` in 2 ways. 1st you can store it in a `cookie`/`storage` and read it from the other page. 2nd and the one i recommend you can simply redirect the page with query in the function like

```
function book_now(elem){
  var flight_no = elem.parentNode.parentNode.children[1].innerHTML;
  window.open("2ND_PAGE_URL?flight_no=" + flight_no, "_self");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i have one more doubt , can i set that var and get it on other page or will i need to convert it into a string and then i will be able to set it and get it on other jsp page ???

Comment: Check my edit to see the ways to send the value to another page

Comment: Thanku very much. i am able to get it on other jsp page. Thanks alot :) stackoverflow is best (Y)